# How can I read the Body of the DefaultHttpContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpcontext

I am writing a test that uses `DefaultHttpContext` in its call (`startup` is the test subject here):

```
[Fact]
public async void HandleCabinet_ShouldReturnValidCabinetSettings()
{
    var startup = new Startup();
    var context = DefaultHttpConext();

    await startup.HandleCabinet(context);

    string body;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(context.Response.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        body = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    Assert.Equal("some expectation", body);
}
```

The problem is, `body` is always an empty string. In the `HandleCabinet` method, I write something into it like this:

```
await context.Response.WriteAsync("some expectation");
```

I saw by default, `Body` is a `NullStream`, so I tried setting a stream like this:

```
context.Response.Body = new BufferedStream(new MemoryStream());
```

but, that has no effect.

So, how can I construct the `DefaultHttpContext`, such that I can test the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `MemoryStream` and reset the position to 0.

e.g.

Creating the `DefaultHttpContext`:

```cs
private DefaultHttpContext CreateHttpContext()
{
    var context = new DefaultHttpContext
    {
        Response =
        {
            Body = new MemoryStream()
        }
    };
    return context;
}
```

Body to string: (note: C# 9 syntax)

```
public static string StreamToString(Stream stream)
{
    stream.Position = 0;
    using StreamReader reader = new(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

The assertion:

```cs
var body = StreamToString(context.Response.Body);
Assert.Equal("some expectation", body);
```

The setup I use for creating the `DefaultHttpContext`